Rust From Implementation for Vec<T>
Given the code

struct NodeFragment{
    char: String,
    name: String,
    cost: i32,
    r#type: String
}

pub struct Node {
    pub char_name: String,
    pub node_name: String,
    pub cp_cost: i32,
    pub node_type: NodeType,
}

impl From<Node> for NodeFragment{
    fn from(value: Node) -> Self {
        NodeFragment{ char: value.char_name, name: value.node_name, cost: value.cp_cost, r#type: value.node_type.to_string() }
    }
}

impl From<Vec<Node>> for NodeFragment{
    fn from(value: Vec<Node>) -> Vec<NodeFragment> {
        //foreach mapping value to Vec<NodeFragment>
        vec![]
    }
}

I get that error:
method `from` has an incompatible type for trait
expected signature `fn(Vec<_>) -> NodeFragment`
   found signature `fn(Vec<_>) -> Vec<NodeFragment>`rustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
main.rs(34, 34): change the output type to match the trait: `NodeFragment`

How do i implement the method from for a Vec<Node> to get a Vec<NodeFragment>?
The concept for the from Trait i assume is, that i convert Type A to Type B. The error message above, doesn't give me any details. Is it not allowed to implement from for Vec Type outside of the Vec crate?

Once you have an impl From<Node> for NodeFragment {}, you can create a Vec<Node> -> Vec<NodeFragment> transform by placing .into_iter().map(NodeFragment::from).collect::<Vec<_>>() on your vec of nodes.

The error message is quite explicit, when implementing From for a type U, the required method from's signature is fn (T) -> U.
In your case, T = Vec<Node> and U = NodeFragment, therefore the required method is fn from(value: Vec<Node>) -> NodeFragment.
What you are attempting to do would require T = Vec<Node> and U = Vec<NodeFragment>, but you cannot implement a foreign trait (std::convert::From) on a foreign type (std::vec::Vec).
You cannot use the From trait to implement your conversion method, and should rely on a custom method / trait to do that.
